# Finding the limit of a complex number as it tends to infinity

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve a complex variable limit question. It proceeds as follow:

Definition: We say that $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = \infty$ if for any $R>0$ there exits $S>0$ such that if $|z|>S$, then $|f(z)|>R$

Use the above definition to prove that $\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{z^3}{z^2+4z} = \infty$

This is how I proceed with the question: Given any R we have

$|\frac{z^3}{z^2+4z}| >R $, then $|\frac{z^2}{z+4}| = |z||\frac{z}{1+\frac{4}{z}}| > R$. Now we know that since z tends to infinity $|z| > 1$ so $|1+\frac{4}{z}| < 4 ...$. However, that's all I got up-to. I was thinking of showing the the fraction $|\frac{z}{1+\frac{4}{z}}| < X$ then $S = \frac{R}{X}$ would meet the inquelity. Any help ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Whan you wrote $f(z)>R$, my guess is that you meant $\bigl|f(z)\bigr|>R$.

Comment: Sorry, yes that's exactly what I meant. I've now changed the equation.

Comment: $|\frac{z^3}{z^2+4z}|=|z-4+\frac{16}{z+4}|\geq|z|-|4+\frac{14}{z+4}|\geq|z|-4-\frac{16}{|z|-4}$. If $|z|>S>4$, then $|\frac{z^3}{z^2+4z}|>|z|-4-\frac{16}{S-4}$. Now pick $S$ such that $S-4-\frac{16}{S-4}>R$.

Comment: Why did the $|z|+4$ change sign half way through ? and I'm guessing the 14 is a typo